# RSS/XML/JSon based Translation Service

Tags: translation, services

Is there such web service to request translation of the word and get the result in some more structured method rather than HTML, like mentioned in subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and the google translation API does not fit your needs?

- http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Translation

eg, querying:

```
 http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=hello%20world&langpair=en|it
```

results nicely in:

```
{
   "responseData": {"translatedText":"ciao a tutti"}, 
   "responseDetails": null, 
   "responseStatus": 200}
```

Comment: excellent, do you happen to know the dictionary API somewhere, which will provide detailed explanation of word?

Comment: i didnt get what you are asking for ... do you want a detailed description of the result? http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/reference.html#ResultObjects

Comment: I mean to have dictionary facility instead of translation. Like this one http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hinder. You give a word in some language it will give you back variants in English.